# How do I get systemd-modules-load.service back up and running?

Tags: fedora

I had the latest version of fedora, it's my main OS. I tried to run anbox on it and it wouldn't work, on one of the forums I found a solution, it was about changing modules-load.d (I can't say exactly because I don't remember), it didn't work, and afterwards for other reasons I forgot to octatet everything back and changed fedora to a neighboring OS. As a result, when I tried to enter fedora again, it loaded endlessly, I went to the text format of the download and there was an error:

```
failed to start systemd-modules-load.service - load kernel modules
```

I started looking for an answer on different forums, there were basically two answers, boot without this service and then fix everything while being directly in the system (I don't know how it works considering that this service starts the kernel as I understand) or roll it back. The problem is that CTRL + ALT + F..... did not allow me to enter the console. I found the only option that worked for me is to edit the kernel startup parameters by writing rd.break at the end and boot with these parameters, as a result, the kernel startup stops and opens sh console, but this console is cut down in capabilities and it did not give much help. I tried journalctl (if I am not mistaken in the name of the command) and there were no fixed errors, then tried systemctl status systemd-modules-load and surprisingly everything works there, also scrolled through all the logs (I do not remember what command) and there were errors as I understand with services that are not directly related to my problematic service. Restarting the service or disabling the service did not help me at all, I still can not log in( I will be glad to any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it will help someone, I dug into the system and found in the directory /etc/modules-load.d/ file anbox.conf I set it correspondingly for anbox, but I removed anbox, but the configuration file remained, which caused an error because it could not find the modules that need to run, removing the directory modules-load.d completely solved my problem